# How to Add Data into Existing Index in Elasticsearch using Olivere Package

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I am not sure whether it is correct or not. But I think that if I want to add data into existing index in elasticsearch using olivere in golang, the only option available is to delete the index and re index the data.

This is my code :

```
bulkRequest := client.Bulk()
        for j := 0; j < 20; j++ {

            n++
            tweet := Tweet{User: "Rudi", Message: "This is the new from string representations of basic data types. " + strconv.Itoa(n)}
            req :=
                elastic.NewBulkIndexRequest().Index("employee").Type("tweet").Id(strconv.Itoa(n)).Doc(tweet)
            bulkRequest.Add(req)

        }

        bulkResponse, err := bulkRequest.Do(context.Background())
```

Does anyone know a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think you have to delete the index first?

Comment: Because it doesn't work. Do you know how to insert data into existing index in elasticsearch using olivere in golang? I tried to insert new data into existing data, but it doesn't work. I use ES 6.4.3, but it didn't work when inserting new data into existing index. There is no new data inserted.

Comment: Presumably because you are using the same document IDs every time.

Comment: no, I change the id in the next insert, but it still didn't work